# Calculating the coordinates of a linear function.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B=(1,0,1),(0,1,2),(1,1,0)$ be a basis of $R^3$. Calculate the dual basis         $B$ and the coordinates of the linear function $w(x,y,z,t)=2x-y-z$

I have calculated the dual basis: $B^*=(2/3,-2/3,1/3)$. How can I calculate the coordinates of the linear function $w(x,y,z,t)=2x-y-z$ in this basis?

Comment: Do you know what the coordinates of $w$ are in the standard basis?

Comment: @amd I don't know, all the problem statement is the first parahraph of the my post.